# Нет выбора позиции в joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, php, html, css

Тут скриншот:

[image]

И там почему-то нет выпадающего списка для выбора позиции, а надо самому писать...а как узнать какие имеются позиции у шаблона хз.
Че можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщето на сколько я помню позиции прописывабтся в папке с шаблоном в файле templateDetails.xml там есть тэги

```
<positions>
    <position>позиция</position>
<positions>
```

Все прописанные позиции в этом файле и будут в выпадающем списке шаблона.

Comment: Вообще с помощью этого файла можно настраивать шаблон как хочется.
Ну для примера вот статья 

http://template-master.ru/joomla/templatedetails-xml-joomla-template-description.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.example.com**?tp=1**

Comment: Это если в настройках включена опция разрешающая отображать позиции.

Comment: Да. Насколько я знаю - включена по умолчанию.